# How to change HwndSource window size C#

Tags: c#, resize, window, hwndsource

I created a window as a child window of a C++ window handler in C#, the code is like:

```
public void CreateHostHwnd(IntPtr parentHwnd)
        {
            // Set up the parameters for the host hwnd.
            parentHandle = parentHwnd;
            HwndSourceParameters parameters = new HwndSourceParameters("Video Window", 351, 295);
            parameters.WindowStyle += WS_CHILD;
            parameters.SetPosition(0, 0);
            parameters.ParentWindow = parentHwnd;

            // Create the host hwnd for the visuals.
            HwndSource myHwndSource = new HwndSource(parameters);
        }
```

However, after this child window is created, I cannot change its size by using

```
parameters.SetSize(width, height);
```

Are there any way to change its size after it is created? 
Thank you~!

Comment: I am not familiar with this but I saw in the MSDN that there is a SizeToContent property to the HwndSource. Try to set it to SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight. Try also to use width and height instead of SetSize.

Comment: Hi, I tried that before, it makes some change to it but not as what I want, I will read a little more about SizeToContent, maybe it is the one should be used, thank you~!

Comment: Ok, try to look also at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676649/attach-window-to-window-of-another-process

Comment: Hi, still cannot change the size, this one shows how to initialize a window but after its created, still cannot change its size.